# SSDT For VS2013 Not Displaying SQL Server 2014 as Target Version

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I am using SSDT for creating reports for SSRS 2014. I have SQL Server 2014 installed on my machine. I am able to create the reports there is no issue there.

When I deploy, I tried to change the Target Version, SSDT is showing only SQL Server 2008 & SQL Server 2008 R2 and later as the options. Why is not displaying SQL Server Server 2014? I tried 'Detect Version...' option too but still it is pointing only to 2008 and later.

When I went back and checked the schema of the `.rdl` files I was surprised to see the 2008 Schema not the 2010 schema which is the default for 2014.

Questions :

- Why is the schema is still 2008 and not 2010 in SSDT?
- Why is SSDT not detecting SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 2):

The schema for SQL Server Reporting Services is 2010 (i.e. SQL Server 2008 R2).  You can confirm this by checking the targetNamespace attribute returned by the root node returned by the following URL (from the report server):

http://localhost/reportserver/reportdefinition.xsd

There were no RDL schema changes in SQL 2012 or 2014.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms170438(v=sql.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms170438(v=sql.120).aspx

This is the same reason why the SSDT deployment is going to "SQL Server 2008 R2 or later".

So in summary, your environment is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answers to your questions can be found in the following MSDN post:
[Plan for Report Design and Report Deployment (Reporting Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207009.aspx)

I'll quote the parts most  relevant to your questions:

> When you open a report in Report Designer in SQL Server Data Tools
>   (SSDT), the report definition is upgraded to the currently supported
>   RDL schema. When you specify a SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2,
>   SQL Server 2012, or SQL Server 2014 report server in the project
>   properties, the report definition is saved in a schema that is
>   compatible with the target server.
>
> Reports are not upgraded when you upload a report definition file
>   directly to the report server or SharePoint site. Upgrading a report
>   definition in SQL Server Data Tools is the only way to upgrade the
>   .rdl file.

In the table below, only the top row is relevant to your situation. The deploy version is different to the authored and for SQL Server 2014 this appears to be 2008 RDL as default.

> The following table summarizes support for authoring and deploying report definitions for different schema versions
>   [image]

Here you can see that VS 2013 only has the 2008 RDL available which explains why you're not getting the option for 2010.

> The following table provides the list of RDL versions supported by the
>   ReportViewer controls for local processing (.rdlc). Server side RDL
>   support is summarized in the section Report Server and RDL Schema
>   Support.
>
> [image]